# Angular2 Boolean @Input property getting set as string - binding nested properties

Tags: angular

I have an outer component with a property:

```
Loading: Boolean = false;
```

this outer component is setting this property on a nested component:

```
<etp-loader text="loading..." loading="{{Loading}}"></etp-loader>
```

when I do typeof(this.Loading) on the nested component, I get string, which [what i believe] is what throws off the whole logic.

here's my nested component:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core'
@Component({
    selector: 'etp-loader',
    template: `<div *ngIf="loading" class="progress" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0"
                        aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%;">
                        {{text}}
                </div>
                </div>`
})
export class EtpLoaderComponent {
    @Input()
    text: string;

    @Input()
    loading: Boolean;    

    ngOnInit() {
        console.debug('init: loader state: ', 
                       this.loading, 
                       typeof(this.loading)); // => init: loader state:  false string
    }
}
```

*edit* - removed irrelevant bits

Comment: The typescript type boolean is all lowercase. Can you try it this way?
Also, you are assigning the loading value wrong: Try: <etp-loader [loading]="Loading">

Comment: bolean did't make a difference but [loading] was the issue :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If `Loading` is a boolean value, then use

```ts
[loading]="Loading"
```

`{{}}` is string interpolation and the result will always be a string.

Angular doesn't know about boolean attributes.
If you just want to know if a property is set or not, you can use a setter like

```ts
isLoading:Boolean;

@Input()
loading set(value: Boolean) {
  this.isLoading = value != 'false';
}
```

and use it like

```ts
<etp-loader loading>
```

and `isLoading` will be set to `true`

Comment: thanks! very good to know about {{}} always string, makes perfect sense now.

Comment: BOO on angular. YAY for your answer!

Comment: @EricNovins no idea what the "BOO" is about, but thanks for the "YAY" :-)

Comment: May be the "BOO" was like me I specified ShowIndex="false" in the HTML template, ie, passing a literal FALSE, and I was getting a string "false", changed it to [ShowIndex]="false" even though I don't have a variable named "false" nor do I intend to bind this param necessarily :)